# picture analysis - human figure picture is straight

Tags: c#, image, image-rotation

I'm looking for a way to analyze an image ( the human figure ) and verify whether it is necessary to rotate the image or images straight.

i'm using c# env.

Comment: Have you tried anything, looked up any image processing libraries?

Comment: This is very broad. Any suggestions I might make would be based on one of several unstated assumptions.

Comment: i'm looking for image proccessing libsraries ..didn't really know how to look for one ,or another idea

Answer (score 1):

If you could detect the eyes then you could figure out if the image should be rotated using the eyes positions.

if (eye1.y - eye2.y) > (eye1.x - eye2.x) => the image should be rotated

Of course you would have to check and subtract the smaller value from the higher value when you calculate the position difference in order for this to work

Comment: the problem is i don't know how to detect the eyes ..